# How to format the log scale with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to make a plot on a Log scale. I need to start the log x axis
  from zero. For an example 0, 10^0, 10^1, 10^2 so on

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = db5.Var1
sns.distplot(x,hist_kws=dict(cumulative=True),kde_kws=dict(c‌​umulative=True),hist‌​=False,color='green'‌​)
plt.xlabel('Seconds')
plt.ylabel('CDF')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xlim(0)
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(loc='right')
plt.title('CDF')
```

Comment: Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?). Do not ask us to write code for you, instead attempt to write code, and when facing an issue, we will try to help.

Answer (score 2):

You need matplotlib.pyplot.xticks. In your example:

xticks(x_values)
Prepend the function call with the module name, depending on your imports.

For instance, in ipython --pylab I enter:

In [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiAdn.png): x_values = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

In [2]: scatter(x_values, x_values)
Out[2]:

In [3]: xticks(x_values)
and get

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiAdn.png)

Note that this leaves some space at the right, because initially the ticks were up to 120 at every 20. To have it at every 10 without knowing the maximum, you can make two calls to xticks:

xticks(range(0, int(xticks()[0][-1])+1, 10))